# sqlite3.h not found error on CircleCI on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, circleci

I'm facing a problem with CircleCI.

The iOS app compiles perfectly on my local machine, but seems that CircleCi doesn't have the sqlite3.h file on their machines, or at least it is not in the same directory.

Here the part of the CicleCI log:
[image]

This problem it's related with a pod named *GRDB.swift*. if I open the module this is what I see:
[image]

how I can solve it?

Comment: May be add `- run: brew upgrade sqlite3` before in steps section in your config.yml ?

Answer (score 0):

Swift module maps contain absolute paths. And that's very painful, because this forces Xcode to be located in a specific place.

A solution would be to have the CircleCI put Xcode at its regular place. Another solution would be to modify the module map before building.

Please tell use your final solution, because it will be invaluable for many users.